# Загрузить результат игры на Unity в FB и Twitter

Tags: c#, unity3d

Столкнулась с проблемой того, как запостить счет игры в FB и Twitter. Сам скрипт есть и все работает,но отправляет только сообщения записанного изначально в переменную текста.
Вопрос в том, как добавить переменную, в которой записан счет игры. Переменная находиться в другом файле, в другом классе.
Выходит получить доступ к методу из того класса. Но результат этого доступа никуда не получается записать и добавить.

Это кусок кода в котором лежит та самая переменная:

```
public class GameOverScript : MonoBehaviour 
{
    int score = 0;

    public void Start ()
    {
        score = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Score");
    }
...
}
```

Скрипт для Twitter-а:

```
public class Twitscript : MonoBehaviour  
{

    const string Address = "http://twitter.com/intent/tweet";
    public void Sharetweet()
    {
        Application.OpenURL(Address +
            "?text=" + WWW.EscapeURL("Hurraahh! My Score in Test Game is: ") +
            "&amp;url=" + WWW.EscapeURL("\t") +
            "&amp;related=" + WWW.EscapeURL("\t") +
            "&amp;lang=" + WWW.EscapeURL("en"));
    }
}
```

Нужно как-то вытащить переменную score из класса GameOverScript и добавить в эту строчку(настолько я понимаю) `"?text=" + WWW.EscapeURL("Hurraahh! My Score in Test Game is: ")`

Comment: Метод Sharetweet сделайте принимающим строку и передавайте очки, откуда надо.

Comment: А в какой момент и откуда вызывается `Sharetweet()` ?

Comment: Можно немного подробнее о том, как сделать его принимающим строку?

Comment: Скрипт в котором Sharetweet() навешен на кнопку. По нажатию открывается twitter и запрашивается подтверждение публикации

Comment: @Anstsiya самый банальный способ это в методе `Sharetweet` сделать `var myScore = GameObject.Find("ИмяОбъктаСоСкриптомGameOverScript").GetComponent<GameOverScript>().score` и далее этот `myScore` подставить в выражение...Хотя лучше конечно взять переменную через геттер...... у вас в процессе игры как и где в `score` что-то записывается? а в `PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Score")` как и где?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предложу следующий вариант:

```
    int _score = 0;
    public int score
    {
        get { return _score; }
        private set { _score = value; }
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        score = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Score");
    }
```

Тогда при публикации счёта вам понадобится экземпляр класса GameOverScript у которого теперь есть свойство score которое доступно для чтения. т.е. если скажем переменная содержащая экземпляр класса GameOverScript  называется CurentGameOverRezult то публикация будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
Application.OpenURL(Address +
        "?text=" + WWW.EscapeURL("Hurraahh! My Score in Test Game is: "+CurentGameOverRezult.score ) +
        "&amp;url=" + WWW.EscapeURL("\t") +
        "&amp;related=" + WWW.EscapeURL("\t") +
        "&amp;lang=" + WWW.EscapeURL("en"));
```

Если, скажем, в коде который публикует данные о текущей игре получить экземпляр класса GameOverScript в котором хранятся данные о счёте игры который надо опубликовать не представляется возможным, то можно сделать следующее дополнение к приведённому выше коду:

```
static int _score = 0;
    public static  int score
    {
        get { return _score; }
        private set { _score = value; }
    }
```

И тогда соответственно публикация будет иметь вид:

```
 Application.OpenURL(Address +
        "?text=" + WWW.EscapeURL("Hurraahh! My Score in Test Game is: "+GameOverScript.score ) +
        "&amp;url=" + WWW.EscapeURL("\t") +
        "&amp;related=" + WWW.EscapeURL("\t") +
        "&amp;lang=" + WWW.EscapeURL("en"));
```

В данном случае поле _score и свойство score стали статическими, что с одной стороны позволяет получать значение свойства score не создавая/получая экземпляр класса, а с другой налагает ограничения на использование score. Если экземпляров класса GameOverScript у вас может быть больше чем 1 в какой-то момент времени, то во всех этих экземплярах свойство score будет иметь одинаковое значение.

UPD:
Перечитал ещё раз вопрос и понял, что в вашем случае оптимальным будет следующий вариант:

```
public int score
{
    get { return PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Score"); }
}
```

Если у вас

> Выходит получить доступ к методу из того класса

То совершенно таким же образом вы сможете получить доступ и к свойству score этого класса. Которое будет возвращать искомый вами счёт игры.

Comment: Ошибку выдает вот такую:
Error CS0120 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'GameOverScript.score'

Comment: Он ругается на то, что поле GameOverScript.score не static. Не уверен что для последнего предложенного варианта данный модификатор доступен, но попробуйте изменить public int score.... на public static int score. 
А вообще в этом месте: WWW.EscapeURL("Hurraahh! My Score in Test Game is: "+GameOverScript.score ) данные о счёте следует получать так же, как вы получали доступ к методу из этого класса. (я полагаю этим методом был Start () )

Comment: Опять же, как было предложено ниже, скорее всего возможно сделать так:  WWW.EscapeURL("Hurraahh! My Score in Test Game is: "+PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Score" ) но сработает ли это сказать наверняка невозможно пока иерархия классов и модификаторы используемых методов остаются для нас неизвестными...

Answer (score 1):

А почему нельзя сделать так:
в методе Sharetweet

```
score = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Score");
```

Или получить `instance` класса GameOverScript и вызвать на нем метод `getScore` для получения счета.